# How to get the request object for MaxUploadSizeExceededException

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller-advice

I'm developing a RESTful api using spring boot 2 and trying to upload a file with limit set in the yml file as `servlet.multipart.max-file-size=2MB`.

As per my requirement any file size uploaded above 2MB need to inserted into the database with the request information (`getUser()`) and the exception. I'm able to generate the exception message using `@ExceptionHandler` but i do not get the request information (`getUser()`). please advise.

I tried with WebRequest webRequest on the rest controller with webRequest.setAttribute but I get Null in the `@ExceptionHandler`.

My Controller and Controller advice:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/sendEmail")
    public ResponseEntity<EmailVO> sendEmail(@RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile[] uploadfile,
            @RequestPart EmailVO emailVO,WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest httprequest) {
        webRequest.setAttribute("emailVO", emailVO, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        EmailVO emailVO = myService.sendEmail(emailVO, uploadfile);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(emailVO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ExceptionResponse handleException(final Exception ex, final HttpServletRequest httprequest,WebRequest webrequest) {
        if (ex instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) { 
            EmailVO  emailVO  = (EmailVO) webrequest.getAttribute(EmailVO, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
            return new ExceptionResponse("Exceeds the limit for user "+emailVO.getUser,ex.getClass().getSimpleName(), httprequest.getRequestURI(),"Failure");
        } 
    }
```

I'm unable to get the emailVO.getUser which is coming from the request controller

Comment: Do you want to know the user who uploaded bigger file ?

Comment: No.. what ever json object i sent in the POST request i want in the controller advice so that i can insert into the database about the request and the error i got on the maxuploadsizeexceededlimit

Comment: You can wrap EmailVO object inside the Exception object. Create separate method called handleMaxSizeUploadException(...).

Comment: @Sambit i'm not able to get what your trying to explain me, do u want to have another method in handleMaxSizeUploadException() in controller advise but how do i wrap the VO object in exception object? Please elaborate. Thank you